# Numba, strange type modification

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to further speed up some code written in python, compiled using Numba. When looking at the assembly generated by numba, I noticed double-precision operations being generated, which I felt was odd since the inputs and outputs are all supposed to be float32.

I declare the variable/array types as float32 outside of the jitted loop and pass them into the function. Strangely, I find that after running my tests, the variable "scalarout" is converted to python float, which is actually a 64 bit value.

My code:

```
from scipy import ndimage, misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.fft
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numba
# numba.config.DUMP_ASSEMBLY = 1
from numba import float32
from numba import jit, njit, prange
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

# import llvmlite.binding as llvm
# llvm.set_option('', '--debug-only=loop-vectorize')

@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=False)
def mydot(a, b, xlen, ylen, scalarout):
    scalarout = (np.float32)(0.0)
    for y in prange(ylen):
        for x in prange(xlen):
            scalarout += a[y, x] * b[y, x]
    return scalarout

# ======================================== TESTS ========================================

print()
xlen = 100000
ylen = 16
a = np.random.rand(ylen, xlen).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.rand(ylen, xlen).astype(np.float32)
print("a type = ", type(a[1,1]))
scalarout = (np.float32)(0.0)
print("scalarout type, before execution = ", type(scalarout))
iters=1000

time = 100.0
for n in range(iters):
    start = timer()
    scalarout = mydot(a, b, xlen, ylen, scalarout)
    end = timer()
    if(end-start < time):
        time = end-start
print("Numba njit function time, in us = %16.10f" % ((end-start)*10**6))
print("function output = %f" % scalarout)
print("scalarout type, after execution = ", type(scalarout))
```

Comment: You can get the internal types using `mydot.inspect_types()`. `scalarout = np.float32(0.)` or defining locals eg. `@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=False,locals={"scalarout": numba.types.float32})`. There is only max. 5% performance benefit (the problem mainly limited by memory bandwidth), the difference of the result due to the lower precision is more noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer. If you change the `scalarout` to be a float32 array of length 1 and modify that, your output is float32.

```py
@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=False)
def mydot(a, b, xlen, ylen):
    scalarout = np.array([0.0], dtype=np.float32)
    for y in prange(ylen):
        for x in prange(xlen):
            scalarout[0] += a[y, x] * b[y, x]
    return scalarout
```

If you change `return scalarout` to `return scalarout[0]`, then the output is again a python float.

In your original code for `mydot`, the result is a python float even if you write `return np.float32(scalarout)`.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, and it does force the output type to np.float32. Unfortunately it causes the function to execute about 5x slower.